# Magento - get list of items from orders for specific date range

Tags: database, magento

Magento database name convention is not trivial. How to get these fields below for last 7 days?

Last Name
First Name
Address
City
State
Zip
Phone
Email
Amount 
Order #
Item #

Answer (score -2):

I could not tell if you were looking for some PHP/Magento code or if you are looking to access the database directly.  It might be "better" to create yourself a custom module that fetches this info using the Magento/Zend framework, but since I don't know the code off the top of my head I'll redirect you to the following link which has a very nice SQL query that will pull that info for you (and more).

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/207/fedex_-_shipping_view

You probably just need to add something like this to the end to filter the last 7 days

```
where so.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: whats up with the downpoint?  Was there some type of misinformation in the answer?